# How to get front action from admin in magento 2

Tags: magento2, admin, url

In my custom module i call one custom phtml.

In there is one button on that click i want to redirect front action

How can i call front action from admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get frontend url using below method,

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

//Here 1 is store front url
$frontUrl = $om->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore(1)->getUrl('customer/account/create');
echo $frontUrl;
```

Thanks.